# What does this template parameter mean?

Tags: c++, templates

For the following code, what does `std::uint64_t = 0` mean?

```
template< class T, std::uint64_t = 0 >
struct Dummy {  
   T value;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a non-type template parameter of type `std::uint64_t` with a default value of `0`.

Note that the parameter is unnamed, so you can't use it directly in `Dummy`.

However, there are still several uses for this template parameter, e.g. you can use a different value for this parameter to select specializations of `Dummy`:

```
// specialization
template< class T>
struct Dummy<T, 42> {
   // ... 
};
```

Now `Dummy<int>` or `Dummy<int, 0>` will use the primary template, but `Dummy<int, 42>` will use the partial specialization. One of the common uses of this is in a technique called SFINAE.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst [@cigien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64283002/4573247) covers the general description of this class template:

- two template parameters, where,
- the first is a *type template parameter*, and where
- the second a **non-named** *non-type template parameter* which has a *default argument value* of `0`,

it may be good to point out that you can still access the non-named non-type template parameter by partially specializing the class template `Dummy` over a fixed type for the type template parameter, whilst adding a name for the non-type template parameter for which the partial specialization is still parameterized.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template< class T, std::uint64_t = 0 >
struct Dummy {
   T value;
};

// Partial specialization where the remaining non-type
// template parameter is given a name which in turn can
// be used within the class template definition blueprint
// for this specialization.
template<std::uint64_t NUM>
struct Dummy<std::uint64_t, NUM> {
    // Use the named non-type template parameter to define
    // a default member initializer for the value member.
    std::uint64_t value{NUM};
};

int main() {
    std::cout 
        << Dummy<std::uint64_t, 42>{}.value  // 42 (<uint64_t, 42> specialization)
        << Dummy<std::uint32_t>{}.value      // 0  (<uint32_t, 0> specialization)
        << Dummy<std::uint32_t, 42>{}.value; // 0  (<uint32_t, 42> specialization)
                             // ^^ - template argument '42' is not used in the 
                             //      primary template (other than encoding the type)
}
```

Comment: This is a nice use case, especially because it's not very common :) (I think).

Comment: @cigien I agree that it's uncommon for my own common cases, but it may actually be a more common partial class specialization for the regular non-metaprogramming C++ developer. Sometimes I get the feeling that us C++/templates SO:ers are a bit damaged by all the meta-programming that we forget that templates can also be used in non-meta contexts :D

Comment: Haha, very true, and guilty as charged ;)